# Powershell: How to use -Context Parameter Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to  use my StorageAccount-Context for a task, but it fails.

I've followed the Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.storage/new-azstoragecontext?view=azps-5.4.0

```
$storageAccountRG = "myrg"
$storageAccountName = "myaccount"
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $storageAccountRG -AccountName $storageAccountName).Value[0]
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
```

When I run `Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount -Context $ctx`

it fails:

```
Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount: Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of type "System.String" to type "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IStorageContext".
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly is the content of `$ctx` ? It should not be a string, but the exception indicates that it is. Is it possible, that you hard-typed the variable like `[string]$ctx` somewhere in your code?

Comment: `($ctx).GetType()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- --------      ----                                           --------
True     False    AzureStorageContext              System.Object`

Comment: @Gill-Bates, please check which version of the `Az.Storage` module you're using. You can use this powershell cmdlet `Get-InstalledModule` to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh dear! I have finally solved it! Google has routed me to an outdated Documentation. So I messed the cmdlets up!

`New-AzureStorageContext` is not `New-AzStorageContext`

**Thanks all for helping out!**

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error :

```
Cannot bind parameter 'Context'. Cannot convert the "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext" value of type "System.String"
```

Ran the below snippet at my end :

```
$storageAccountRG = "myrg"
$storageAccountName = "myaccount"
$storageAccountKey = (Get-AzStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $storageAccountRG -AccountName $storageAccountName).Value[0]
$ctx = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
```

Ran `get-member` for `$ctx`

I see the correct type associated with `$ctx` - **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext**

[image]

You re likely encountering the issue because of `$ctx` is overwritted by a string value in your code. (Which you have not shared in the code)

Before running this :
`Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount -Context $ctx`

Try running `$ctx | gm` to understand what type is it.  If typename is String (instead of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.AzureStorageContext`)

You will have to trace back in your code - to understand where exactly this was changed.
Alternatively you can share the complete script for a better understanding.

Comment: Also quick thing to note - I think you have stored the `typename` of the $ctx variable in $ctx and then you have run `Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount`

Comment: Thanks for reproducing. The problem is not to fill the $ctx variable. But the problem arises when I want to pass it to the cmdlet `Set-AzCurrentStorageAccount $ctx`

Comment: I undertstand - the error /problem is because of the value that is present in the `$ctx`. You will have to check what is present in the variable